# Guice configuration errors:No implementation for xxx was bound

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

My handler class:

```
public class Handler {

      private final IStore dataStore;

      @Inject
      @Singleton
      public Handler(IStore dataStore) {
          this.dataStore = dataStore;
      }
    }
}
```

My interface class:

```
public interface IStore {}
```

My Impl class:

```
public class DataStoreImpl implements IStore {
  private final JooqTransacter transacter;

  @Inject
  public DataStoreImpl(@Named("XXX") JooqTransacter transacter) {
    this.transacter = transacter;
  }
}
```

My module  class to bind:

```
public class StoreImplModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    bind(IStore.class).to(DataStoreImpl.class);
  }
}
```

When I ran it, I keep getting this error:

```
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for com.xx.store.IStore was bound.
  while locating xxx.IStore
    for the 1st parameter of Handler.<init>(Handler.java:99)
  while locating com.xx.handlers.Handler
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try bind(Handle.class).asEagerSingleton();

Comment: @Justas I tried this, got exactly the same error. thanks

Comment: can you show how the `Injector` is created?